# Convert the JSON attribute from smallcase to uppercase in XQuery and Marklogic 10

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

I have loaded the below JSON in MarkLogic and I need to convert the `Name` property value to upper case:

```
{ "Name": "User", "Id": "1", "date": "2022-01-01" }
```

Any way to convert the value to upper case in Marklogic and XQuery, looking like below format?

```
{ "Name": "USER", "Id": "1", "date": "2022-01-01" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to select the `Name`, use [`upper-case()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:upper-case) and create a `text()` node, and then use [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace).

Assuming that you have the document assigned to a variable `$doc`:

```
let $name := $doc/Name
return xdmp:node-replace($name, text {upper-case($name) } )
```

For reference, there are a few examples in the documentation of updating different types of properties:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_60123